# Копирование и вставка отформатированного текста

Tags: awt, java

Есть небольшое desktop приложение, написанное на java. Я написал код, который позволяет работать из приложения с буфером обмена (т.е. копировать и вставлять текст). А как сделать так, чтобы моё приложение умело копировать в буфер (и доставать) отформатированный текст. То есть чтобы я мог применить шрифт, цвет, размер к тексту, потом скопировать его и вставить, например, в Word и текст был также отформатирован?

Comment: В буфере кроме текста, сохраняется еще чего-то. Вы можете попробовать поискать глубже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да-да. Кроме текста можно выставить mime-type, и тогда можно будет, например, класть text/html, так что ворд сможет получать форматированный текст.

Например, как [здесь: Copying HTML to the clipboard from Java](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2005/01/copying-html-to-clipboard-from-java.html).

Comment: Поискал еще в интернете. Люди утверждают, что можно использовать не HTML, а [RTF][1]. В чем разница и что лучше?


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Comment: HTML проще и все знают его. А формат RTF я лично не помню и он может быть сложен в некоторых случаях. Но в принципе да, можно использовать и другие форматы. Лишь бы ворд его понимал.